# How to install new ATmega firmware via the ISP pins?

Tags: firmware

While uploading [.hex firmware directly](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6654/how-to-install-a-hex-firmware) onto boards that allow this via CURA, this is not always an option for all machines (for lack of a functioning USB-connectable port for example).

On both my TronXY X1 board (Melzi 2.0 V5 with `ATMEGA1284P`) and the Creality Ender 3 (Creality 3D v.1.1.2 with `Δ ATMEL  ATMEGA1284P  AU 1726`) I spotted these 6 pins labeled `ISP` that are supposed to allow to connect an Arduino or similar to flash firmware. According to the RepRap Wiki, Melzi is a derivative of the [Sanguinololu](https://reprap.org/wiki/Melzi) and both are [Sanguino Compatible](https://github.com/Lauszus/Sanguino).

After creating the new firmware in **Arduino IDE** and making sure it compiles for the correct chip in the board, how can I use an Arduino Uno or other microcontroller to flash the new firmware  **via the ISP** to my printer?

This is asking specifically about ATmega based controller boards, using the Arduino toolchain.

Comment: Not all printers are created equal. The process would be very different for a board based on, say, an AtMega2560 than a board based on a Cortex M3. It also depends on what (if any) bootloader is present on the board. I think the question is too broad in its current state.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden true, this is meant as a generic "I have some printer and managed to get the firmware to compile - hw do I get it onto the printer? I have this other microcontroller around". If you can add to the question or reitterate it in a better form, feel free to do so - we pretty much need to answer these basic questions to be able to answer more difficult answers more quickly by interlinking.

Comment: There isn't a one-size-fits-all answer for this. It would be much better to have separate questions for separate types of board, because a single answer can't cover all possible scenario's you're imagining. Keep in mind that [you should only ask practical, answerable questions based on *actual problems that you face*](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). You aren't actually facing the problem of having a board you can't upload to using Cura.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden I know it is supposed to work, but I fail to understand why it is supposed to be better than for example directly loading it via CURA or a different method to send the compiled .hex to the board... After all you have to *open your machine*... But it is a rather universal solution and would work for pretty much any machine - even ones that have no possibility to connect it to the PC, for exampe if the USB port was broken.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden - the ATmega on the controller of the Ender-3 does not have a bootloader, apparently, as per [TH3D Unified Firmware Package](https://www.th3dstudio.com/knowledge-base/th3d-unified-firmware/): *CR-10, Ender 2, and Ender 3 Printers need the bootloader. You will need to follow the CR-10 bootloader guide to flash it before you can load the firmware. You can use our [Uno kit](https://www.th3dstudio.com/product/arduino-uno-bootloader-flashing-kit/) to flash the bootloader on your board.* The Uno kit is the ISP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Considering AVR based controller boards...

You might not need an additional Arduino, to serve as an ISP. It really depends upon the board. There are basically three scenarios:

1. Controller board which is Arduino based - Arduino Mega 2560 with a RAMPS 1.4 - *with* a bootloader
2. Controller board which is Arduino based - Arduino Mega 2560 with a RAMPS 1.4 - *without* a bootloader
3. Controller board which is AVR based board (no separate Arduino board) - as is the case with an Ender-3 and the TronXY board<sup>1</sup> - *without* a bootloader

Option 1 is the easiest, and you simply upload with the USB cable, directly from the Arduino IDE.

Options 2 and 3 is where you would require an In-circuit Serial Programmer (ISP). Such as a USBasp: [USBasp - USB programmer for Atmel AVR controllers](https://www.fischl.de/usbasp/)

[image: USBasp]

or you can use another Arduino, see [Arduino as ISP and Arduino Bootloaders](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP).

An ISP device basically converts the USB to TTL signals (along with a serial protocol (JTAG or derivative)) which then connects to the ICSP<sup>2</sup> interface on the controller board:

[image: ICSP connector]

#### Scenario 1

As stated above, you simply connect the board to the PC/Mac using the USB cable and, within the Arduino IDE, you hit **Upload** - ensuring that you have the correct **Board** (i.e. Mega2560) and **Port** selected in the **Tools** menu.

#### Scenario 2

For the Mega2560 the pins the MOSI, MISO and SCK are broken out on to are:

```
Arduino / Genuino Board    MOSI            MISO             SCK       Level
Mega1280 or Mega2560    51 or ICSP-4    50 or ICSP-1    52 or ICSP-3    5V
```

To program the Mega2560 using an Uno, connect as follows:

[image: Uno as ISP programming Mega]

or using the ISP connector (in this diagram the electrolytic capacitor<sup>3</sup> is not shown):

[image: Uno as ISP programming Mega via ICSP connector]

Take note of the electrolytic capacitor<sup>3</sup> on the programming device:

> The 10 µF electrolytic capacitor connected to RESET and
>   GND of the programming board is needed only for the boards that have
>   an interface between the microcontroller and the computer's USB, like
>   Mega, Uno, Mini, Nano. Boards like Leonardo, Esplora and Micro, with
>   the USB directly managed by the microcontroller, don't need the
>   capacitor.

or using the Mega's ICSP connector, from [Atmega bootloader programmer](https://www.gammon.com.au/bootloader) (see [original image](https://www.gammon.com.au/images/Arduino/Atmega_Chip_Detector9.jpg)):

[image: Uno programming a Mega]

Note D10 is used, not `RESET`<sup>4</sup>

#### Scenario 3

So, to use an Arduino Uno on your controller board, which is scenario 3 (an AVR based board, but not an Arduino board per se), you would need to connect the Uno to the ICSP of the controller board like this:

```
ICSP     Uno

MOSI     D11
MISO     D12
SCK      D13
GND      GND
5V       5V
RESET    D10
```

or, like this, from [Chaos Drucker - CREALITY ENDER3 MIT MARLIN AUSSTATTEN](http://www.chaos-drucker.de/anleitungen-und-tutorials/creality-ender3-mit-marlin-ausstatten/)  (see [original image](https://www.chaos-drucker.de/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Schemata-225x300.jpg)):

**There is an error in the image and the red line should go to `D10` and not `D9` as shown**

[image: Uno to controller board connections]

Note, again, that the `RESET` on the Arduino Uno's ISP connector is **not** used (and Pin 10 is used to connect to the controller's ICSP's `RESET` pin instead)<sup>4</sup>.

#### Configure the Arduino IDE

Then in the Arduino IDE you will need to select the Programmer to be used, in this case *Uno as an ISP*, like so:

[image: Uno as an ISP]

Once you have connected correctly, and selected the programmer, then you *should* be able to hit compile and upload as usual.

---

#### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> Which *both* use the *same* board - see [this answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6342/what-voltage-does-the-creality-ender-3-run-at#answer-6521) to [What voltage does the Creality Ender-3 run at?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6342/what-voltage-does-the-creality-ender-3-run-at)

<sup>2</sup> In case you are wondering, see [What's the difference between ICSP vs ISP?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/19130/whats-the-difference-between-icsp-vs-isp):

> The difference between ISP and ICSP is a hyphen.
>
> ISP stands for In-circuit Serial Programming, and ICSP stands for In
>   Circuit Serial Programming.
>
> Any arrangement that allows you to program a microcontroller while it
>   is in a circuit using a serial protocol can be called ISP or ICSP.

See also [Wikipedia - In-system programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-system_programming).

<sup>3</sup> See [When using an Arduino as an ISP, is the capacitor required or not?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/55498/when-using-an-arduino-as-an-isp-is-the-capacitor-required-or-not)

<sup>4</sup> Why? From [Can the Arduino Uno become an AVR programmer and use the ICSP header to program the target board](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/1003/can-the-arduino-uno-become-an-avr-programmer-and-use-the-icsp-header-to-program):

> First of all, as configured, the RESET pin can not be used as an output pin. In order to use it as an I/O pin, you would have to program the RSTDISBL fuse. But once you do that, as jippie said, it becomes near-impossible to reprogram your Arduino (if you have the socketed through hole variety of the MCU, you could pull it out and put it into a high voltage programmer; in all other cases, it's effectively impossible).
>
> So in theory, you can use the ICSP header the way you suggest. In practice, it's under almost any conceivable circumstance a terrible idea.

Comment: thanks a lot - also I suggest to put up a note reminding to CHECK YOUR CONNECTION WIRES in case some odd error pops up.