# Correct wiring Arduino Uno and GT2560 to install bootloader

Tags: diy-3d-printer, geeetech, arduino

Can anyone help me with the correct wiring between an Arduino Uno and a GT2560 board to install the bootloader using the Arduinio as the ISP.

I'm trying to follow this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2N1zgX8Gv54

But crucially the wiring diagram provided shows 5 connections, but the video shows 6 and they're obscured so it's not clear what was done.

At present I'm getting the following error

`avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000`

Would appreciate any help offered.

Update.

Based on advice received, here is my wiring - I'm still getting the same error. I've checked this several times so apologies if I can't follow basic instructions!

[image: Arduino Uno view]

[image: GT2560 view 1]

[image: GT2560 view 2]

The full error log is as follows:

```
Arduino: 1.6.8 (Linux), Board: "Arduino/Genuino Mega or Mega 2560, ATmega2560 (Mega 2560)"

/home/andy/Desktop/arduino-1.6.8/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -C/home/andy/Desktop/arduino-1.6.8/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega2560 -cstk500v1 -P/dev/ttyACM0 -b19200 >-e -Ulock:w:0x3F:m -Uefuse:w:0xFD:m -Uhfuse:w:0xD8:m -Ulfuse:w:0xFF:m 

avrdude: Version 6.0.1, compiled on Apr 14 2015 at 19:04:16
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/home/andy/Desktop/arduino-1.6.8/hardware/tools/avr/etc/>avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/home/andy/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : /dev/ttyACM0
         Using Programmer              : stk500v1
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 19200
         AVR Part                      : ATmega2560
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PA0
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    10     8    0 no       4096    8      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           flash         65    10   256    0 yes    262144  256   1024  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : STK500
         Description     : Atmel STK500 Version 1.x firmware
         Hardware Version: 2
         Firmware Version: 1.18
         Topcard         : Unknown
         Vtarget         : 0.0 V
         Varef           : 0.0 V
         Oscillator      : Off
         SCK period      : 0.1 us

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000 (retrying)

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000 (retrying)

Error while burning bootloader.
Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000
avrdude: Yikes!  Invalid device signature.
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.


avrdude done.  Thank you.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

Comment: Related to [How to install new ATMEGA firmware via the ISP pins](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6685/how-to-install-new-atmega-firmware-via-the-isp-pins)

Comment: would you provide the error log?

Comment: I found another pinning variant...  It is a pain that the  GT2560  does not come with ICSP interface.

Answer (score 2):

The video [shows 6](https://youtu.be/2N1zgX8Gv54?t=60) in the wiring diagram, but missing one line between 1 and 5V. You can see all the pins used at [this moment](https://youtu.be/2N1zgX8Gv54?t=66) and a little better in [this moment](https://youtu.be/2N1zgX8Gv54?t=68). The first is always the connector, the second the Arduino Uno side:

- 1 to 5V
- 2 to Ground (GND)
- 3 to 10
- 5 to 11
- 10 to 12
- 9 to 13

Note that the revision 3e of the genuine Arduino Uno demands to connect to different pin hoes on the left than the model in the video, **let the labeling guide you**! Instead of 2nd (5V) and 6th (GND) pin-hole on the left side, you'd use the 5th (5V) and 6th or 7th (GND) on the left (counting from the power connection side) or the GND pin on the right, next to digital output 13.

According to [the Arduino Forum](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=391742.0), you might also need a Capacity between Reset and GND on the Arduino Uno.

EDIT: According to [Geeetech](http://www.geeetech.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=17120) we need a **different** Pinning:

[image: Newer Board Pinning]

- LCD 1 to 5V
- LCD 2 to GND
- SD 2 to GND
- SD 3 to 10 (RESET)
- SD 5 to 11 (MOSI)
- SD 10 to 12 (MISO)
- SD 9 to 13 (SCK)