# Palette 2 with an Ender 3 Printer

Tags: print-quality, extruder, ultimaker-cura, creality-ender-3, pallete-2

Has anyone had any luck with printing multi-colored prints with the Palette 2 on an Ender 3? If so, what is your steps/mm for the Ender 3 and your flow rate in whatever slicer you are using? I currently have my flow rate at 100 % and my steps/mm at 104.4, and I believe this is what is causing my Palette 2 to not produce accurate results.

---

**About the Palette 2**

[Palette 2](https://www.mosaicmfg.com/products/palette-2) is a separate device providing one multi color filament out of multiple single color filaments.

As the Ender 3 does not support multi-colour printing, that's why I'm using the Palette 2. It allows any printer to print in multi color as it adds multi color printing to single extruder printers.

Comment: @TreyHope - You need to add more information like what is wrong. Are the colors not changing where you expect them to?

Comment: The OP clearly requires the help from somebody owning both the Ender 3 and the Palette 2, but probably it will be easier for him to contact the Palette customer support...

Comment: What they do need to expand on is what "not produce accurate results" means.

Comment: Hi Trey and welcome to SE.3DP! Please update your question w.r.t. what exactly is the problem and what isn't happening as you expect it to. If you update your question to clarify what is wrong, then the question will be (most likely) reopened. Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: @Greenonline from what I could gather, it seems that you just need to fire up both machines, run the code for the pallete to calibrate the length of the connector tube+bowden tube, then run both machines with the code provided by the slicer - which should run them both to extrude at roughly the same speed forewards  and backwards. though I honestly have no idea how to sync the two as they don't appear to be connected...

Answer (score 2):

On this thread, [Does anyone tried Palette 2.0 on Creality Ender 3 or Ender 3 Pro?](https://support.mosaicmfg.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360021788573-Does-anyone-tried-Palette-2-0-on-Creality-Ender-3-or-Ender-3-Pro-), there are a couple of useful links:

- There is a video, albeit for the CR-10<sup>1</sup>, but that should be of help: [YouTube - Setup Guide: Creality CR-10 with Palette 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5DuGGmxKv94);
- In addition, this Facebook group, [Mosaic Palette, Palette+, Palette 2 (Pro) Users](https://www.facebook.com/groups/mosaic.users/), apparently has some users who have paired their Ender 3 with the Palette 2.

However, *with respect to your question about the flow rate and steps/mm*, there isn't much info out there about that, and no one seems to have experienced similar issues, but your issue *might* have something to do with profiles - which, as you haven't mentioned them in your question, it is hard to know if that might be the issue or not.

In the same thread, [this post](https://support.mosaicmfg.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360021788573/comments/360002849734), states:

> I use it with the Ender 3.  There is a profile in Canvas and Chroma for it also.

This link here, [Chroma for Palette 2](https://support.mosaicmfg.com/hc/en-us/articles/360012415733-Chroma-for-Palette-2), states that *after* using Cura, you then need to load the G-code file into Chroma v3.1, after having selected the appropriate **profile**. However, if you use Canvas, then there is no need for Cura nor Chroma, as Canvas can slice. This link goes through the whole process for Benchy.

---

At the risk of repetition, the process for preparing the print, post-slicing, is also given here, from [Multicolor 3D Printing How To: Using the Mosaic Palette+ with the Creality Ender 3](https://3dprintingcanada.com/blogs/news/multicolor-3d-printing-with-chroma-on-the-creality-ender-3), albeit slightly different from the link above:

> #### Setting Up Chroma:
>
> When you load up Chroma, you’ll be presented with a blank canvas ready
>   to be filled with your 3D creations.  In the top left corner, make
>   sure that you have the **Ender 3** selected from the drop down menu. 
>   After this you can click **Load Print**.  From there you’ll be presented
>   with your gcode files that you have on your computer.
>
> In this example we will be selecting the `butterfly-1.gcode` file, and
>   clicking **Open**.  From here Chroma will be compiling and arranging the
>   settings for the gcode file to be displayed.  This might take a minute
>   or more.
>
> #### Selecting Your Colors:
>
> Once the loading is completed, you will be presented with the 3D
>   rendering of our butterfly!  This butterfly will be in 4 randomly
>   selected colors by default, but we will be changing this next!  To
>   change the colors, navigate to the top of the screen where you will
>   see 4 colored circles, and drop down arrows along with each circle. 
>   These circles represent the colors of each tool head.
>
> To change the color, click on the **Tool Head Colored Circle**, and your
>   options for color will appear, we’re going to select **Black** for our
>   first color.  After this, you will want to select the **Default PLA
>   Settings** by clicking the **Drop Down Arrow** to the right of the first
>   **Tool Head Colored Circle**.
>
> As we make these changes you will notice that the 3D rendering of our
>   butterfly will change to our corresponding colors.  Repeat this
>   process for the remaining 3 Tool Heads, remember to use the **Default
>   PLA Settings** for each Tool Head.
>
> #### Saving Your Project:
>
> After you have selected all your colors, you will click **Save for
>   Printer** in the top right corner of Chroma.  From there, name your
>   file, and click **Save**.  You will be then presented with a loading bar
>   as Chroma prepares our 2 output files.  One of the files will be an
>   adjusted gcode file that has added the purge tower we just modified,
>   and the other file will be a file that goes straight to the Mosaic
>   Palette+.
>
> #### Printing Your Project:
>
> Once the files are ready, you will be presented with a screen that
>   says “Ready to Print!”.  On this screen you will be presented with the
>   files you have created for your project, which for us are the
>   `butterfly-1.msf` which goes to the Mosaic Palette+ and the
>   `butterfly-1.msf.gcode` file which is your newly created gcode file.
>   You will also be presented with “Materials Used” for the project,
>   “Number of Splices” for the project, and “Number of Pings” for the
>   project.
>
> After this, you will need to turn your Creality Ender 3 on if it isn’t
>   already.  After making sure that you have all your **components set up
>   and assembled correctly**, then it is safe to begin the printing
>   process.
>
> Depending on your specific project will determine how long the
>   printing process takes.  But once your printing process is complete
>   you will be presented with your **beautiful multicolored 3D butterfly**
>   (or whatever your project was)!  After printing is finished, you
>   should let the project cool before you attempt to remove it from the
>   tray. Once it has cooled you can now gently pry the project off of the
>   tray.

---

#### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> The CR-10 is, on a broader level, an Ender-3 with 2 lead screws and a slightly different board.

Answer (score 0):

The guide is at [Getting Started With Palette 2 (Setup to Printing)](https://support.mosaicmfg.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011124234-Getting-Started-With-Palette-2-Setup-to-Printing-), which includes guides to use the correct slicer software and swapping [the firmware](https://support.mosaicmfg.com/hc/en-us/articles/360010073234-Firmware-Update).

The latter part may be a little bit of an ordeal on the Ender3 as there is no bootloader on it - however, it is not apparent from the instruction, whether this would be an issue or not - it seems to be a fairly simple process.

> 1. Open your Palette 2 package and remove your Palette 2 unit and USB cable. Connect your Palette 2 to your computer.
>
>    To help the updater recognize the port for your Palette, try
>      unplugging other USB devices.
> 2. Download our Firmware Installer for your operating system.
>
>    Latest Palette Firmware V. 4.2.3 (Mar 14, 2019)
>
>    - Windows (x32 or x64) [Download](https://s3.amazonaws.com/mosaic-resources/p2fwup/latest/Palette+2+Firmware+Updater+Setup+1.1.2.exe)
>    - macOS    [Download](https://s3.amazonaws.com/mosaic-resources/p2fwup/latest/Palette+2+Firmware+Updater-1.1.2.dmg)
>    - Linux (x64, Tested on Ubuntu 16.04)  [Download](https://s3.amazonaws.com/mosaic-resources/p2fwup/latest/Palette+2+Firmware+Updater-1.1.2.dmg)<sup>1</sup>
> 3. Follow the on-screen instructions and click "Install Latest"
> 4. Once the firmware is updated, you will receive the *Success* message, and you can unplug your unit from your computer.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>1</sup> For Linux users, please refer to this [support article](https://support.mosaicmfg.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004996014-Enabling-USB-Serial-Port-Permissions-on-Linux).

Comment: @Trish - Following on from our adventure, when we updated the firmware on an Ender, this process described above seem to be a lot less painful (Plug in USB and run an application). I wonder how that is achieved, with out the ISP programming (see [How to install new ATMEGA firmware via the ISP pins?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/6685/how-to-install-new-atmega-firmware-via-the-isp-pins)). Maybe there is a bootloader, after all?