# Marlin won't start up on modified CR10s

Tags: marlin, creality-cr-10

I have been adding a Hemera and BLTouch to my CR10s, and finally finished everything, flashed the firmware, and everything worked fine. However, I forgot about one thing (`Probe_to_Nozzle_Offset`), so I went back in made the changes, compiled it and that completed successfully. I uploaded it via Cura, and it gave me the `upload finished` message, so I closed Cura and went back to working. However, when I turned the printer off and back on, it wouldn't boot up. It would only show the Marlin screen, see e.g. [this video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXUHx.jpg).

It stays like that for as long as I have looked at it.

Now I am also having troubles uploading new firmware. Cura will not detect the printer is connected, Arduino will not either, and Platformio gives me some `timeout` error, which I looked up and it means that the uploader couldn't connect to the bootloader. I don't know any other way to upload the new firmware, and for now my project is stuck because of it. I have 2 ideas of what happened:

1. The upload was not completed and was therefore corrupted when I closed Cura.
2. The build was broken, but because it compiled fine I don't know how this could be.

Does anyone know what could have happened, or how to fix it?

**EDIT:**

VS code/platform.io recognized the usb port, and tried sending over the `firmware.hex`file, but all I got was this warning over and over:

```
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout
avrdude: stk500v2_getsync(): timeout communicating with programmer
```

And then later:

```
avrdude: stk500v2_command(): failed miserably to execute command 0x10
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.
```

Everything was plugged in, and the lights on the board were being powered by the computer, so there was still a connection, but for some reason this warning happened, and then went right back to the `avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout`

Also, I looked in the device manager when my USB to ISP was connected, and it wouldn't show, which explains why Arduino IDE won't upload the bootloader, but in that case is my only option to buy an Ardunio?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/11338/flashing-a-bootloader-on-ender-3-without-arduino)?

Comment: I have an USB to ISP, but arduino IDE kept saying “error while burning bootloader”

Comment: What most likely happened is that the firmware got corrupted during the transfer. Do you have a way of reverting to the old firmware without dismantling the machine? Don't worry this sort of stuff happens a lot.

Comment: I have a working version of marlin on my computer, but can't upload it

Comment: The same thing just happened to me.
Did you find a solution?

Comment: if you have an ISP connector, you could re-flash the bootloader... then install fresh

Comment: In my case, I happened to remember that I had a old version of marlin on the SD card that came with the printer (I think all of them do), inserting that SD card fixed it (that reinstalls marlin), but if you get a clean card and download marlin to it it should work. I could then install the firmware again, and it worked fine